# I use Hasura on Heroku. How can I move to work locally with a docker with current data?

Tags: docker, heroku, export, hasura

I now work with Hasura deployed on Heroku. I want to start to work locally with the same image.
How can I do it?

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question with more detail. What, specifically, is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since All Hasura's data is stored on a PostgreSQL instance, we need to export the db from heroku to local db installation.

Here is one way to do it:

- **Step 1:**

  Export all data from heroku's postgresql db  first ([read on instructions here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export))
- **Step 2:**

  Create a local Hasura Instance by Docker ([Instructions](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/getting-started/docker-simple.html))
- **Step 3:**

  Import the data back to the PostgreSQL running container that you've created on step 2. ([Instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#restore-to-local-database))

and also export [metadata](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/how-it-works/metadata-schema.html) from the heroku hasura instance (/console/settings/metadata-actions) and import it on the local installation. (to recover the relationship and other schema data)